# MVC4 + Webforms cross project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, merge

I have 2 projects (MVC4 & ASP.NET 3.5). Now i'm intend to render the (etc. : page1.aspx) into my index.cshtml. Is that possible to do it?

This code should not work because it's from another project.

```
   @Html.Partial("~/page1.aspx")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class myTestController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); //Razor file in  Views/folder1/Index.cshtml
    }

    public ActionResult RenderAspx()
    {
        return View("page1"); //Aspx file Views/folder1/page1.aspx
    }
}
```

then in your page

```
@{@Html.RenderAction( "RenderAspx","myTestController");}
```

Comment: hmmm.... page1.aspx is NOT in the same project with Index.cshtml. That's mean their physical path isn't the same.

Comment: I didn't read that! If it is external try to get it via jquery ajax call. Can't you?

Comment: but if do that, browser will need to post back to server to retrieve the page.

Comment: yes but you want an external resource.. I don't see how you can get it without new request (get,post...)

Comment: that's why i wondered it can be done or not :D.... or maybe compiled the aspx to .dll and import to MVC Project (just my guess). Or else i have to merge 2 projects into 1 in-order to shared the _layout.cshtml